# change the values of one select depends on value of another, from database, without refreshing page in php

Tags: php, mysql

Here 'toq' is one select tag and 'sub_toq' is another depends on value of 'toq', want to display the options, having selected 'toq' value, in 'sub_toq', but value must be from database....how to achieve this..in php?

```js
<scipt>
$("#select1").change(function() { 
if(typeof $(this).data('options') === "undefined"); 
var id = $(this).val();
var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
                   $('#select2').html(options);});
</scipt>
```

```html
<select id="toq">
<?php  
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die("unable to connect to my sql");
if(!$conn) { die("Cannot connect to db");}               mysql_select_db("iknow",$conn) or die("UNABLE TO SELECT DB");              $sqlquery = "SELECT header FROM h1 ORDER BY header asc";              
$res = mysql_query($sqlquery);
while($dsatz = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{                 
?>
<OPTION VALUE="<?php echo $dsatz["header"];?>"><?php echo $dsatz["header"];?></OPTION><br>
<?php
}
mysql_close();?>
</select>


<select id="sub_toq">
<?php  
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die("unable to connect to my sql");
if(!$conn) { die("Cannot connect to db");}               mysql_select_db("iknow",$conn) or die("UNABLE TO SELECT DB");              $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM sub ORDER BY sub asc";              
$res = mysql_query($sqlquery);
while($dsatz = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{                 
?>
<OPTION VALUE="<?php echo $dsatz["header"];?>"><?php echo $dsatz["subheader"];?></OPTION><br>
<?php
}
mysql_close();?>
</select>
```

Comment: What're you asking for is generally doable via AJAX.

Comment: I don't know anything about ajax, will you give me coding regarding plz?.... :@Extrakun

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a Q&A site, not a tutorial site. You are best served by getting a solid fundamentals in JS, AJAX and PHP from W3Schools - this way you will be equipped to tackle most of the common questions.

Comment: Hey thank you for suggestion..I just trial & error about some ajax code and got solution....Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can either ensure that the information of the sub_toq is already there when the page is loaded, and use javascript/jQuery to display the correct information, or use AJAX to fetch the results from the database without refreshing the page.

Comment: I 'm unable to load sub_toq at page load..Will you please suggest me coding hint how to do it using jQuery/javascript?...Please

Comment: Hey thank you for suggestion..I just trial & error about some ajax code and got solution....Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here, I got another solution using [link](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/php_drop_down-download.php?download_style=3)...but, I want to achieve this without reloading of page...how to do this?...

```js
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
function reload(form)
   {
 var val=form.cat.options[form.cat.options.selectedIndex].value;
 self.location='index.php?cat=' + val ;
 }          
</script>
```

```html
<?php require 'config.php';  ?>

<?Php
@$cat=$_GET['cat']; //echo "cat :" . @$cat=$_GET['cat']; // Use this line or below line if register_global is off

if(strlen($cat) > 0 and !is_numeric($cat)){ 
// to check if $cat is numeric data or not. 
echo "Data Error";
exit;}

$quer2="SELECT DISTINCT Header,PO FROM h1 order by Header";    
            
echo "<form method=post name=f1 action='dd-check.php'>";
/// Add your form processing page address to action in above line. Example  action=dd-check.php////
///Starting of first drop downlist ////
echo "<select name='cat' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\"><option value=''>Select one</option>";
foreach ($dbo->query($quer2) as $noticia2) {
             if($noticia2['PO']==@$cat){
echo "<option selected value='$noticia2[PO]'>$noticia2[Header]</option>"."<BR>";
}
else{
echo  "<option value='$noticia2[PO]'>$noticia2[Header]</option>";
}
}
echo "</select>";
/////  This will end the first drop down list///////     
//// Starting of second drop downlist /////////

echo "<select name='subcat'><option value=''>Select one</option>";
foreach ($dbo->query($quer) as $noticia) {
echo  "<option value='$noticia[Subheader]'>$noticia[Subheader]</option>";
 }
echo "</select>";
////  This will end the second drop down list /////
//// Add your other form fields as needed here/////
echo "<input type=submit value=Submit>";
echo "</form>";          ?>
```